Homebrew: failed to download; failed to execute
I don't know if this makes any difference, but I'm using macOS 14.5 Sonoma. I have been trying to install Homebrew for hours now and not a single solution I can dig up seems to work.
This is what I'm facing, and I don't know how to fix this:
fenris-esxi@Fenriss-iMac bin % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/Cellar

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/Cellar
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod ug=rwx /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/Cellar
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown fenris-esxi /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/Cellar
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/Cellar
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R fenris-esxi:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 270241, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1598/1598), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (900/900), done.
remote: Total 270241 (delta 769), reused 1378 (delta 614), pack-reused 268643
Receiving objects: 100% (270241/270241), 81.72 MiB | 583.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (194800/194800), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
 * [new branch]            bundle-install-euid     -> origin/bundle-install-euid
 * [new branch]            cask-null-variations    -> origin/cask-null-variations
 * [new branch]            deprecate_command_not_found -> origin/deprecate_command_not_found
 * [new branch]            load-internal-cask-json-v3 -> origin/load-internal-cask-json-v3
 * [new branch]            master                  -> origin/master
 * [new branch]            setup_ruby_command_path -> origin/setup_ruby_command_path
 * [new branch]            tapioca-patch           -> origin/tapioca-patch
 * [new tag]               0.1                     -> 0.1
 * [new tag]               0.2                     -> 0.2
 * [new tag]               0.3                     -> 0.3
 * [new tag]               0.4                     -> 0.4
 * [new tag]               0.5                     -> 0.5
 * [new tag]               0.6                     -> 0.6
 * [new tag]               0.7                     -> 0.7
 * [new tag]               0.7.1                   -> 0.7.1
 * [new tag]               0.8                     -> 0.8
 * [new tag]               0.8.1                   -> 0.8.1
 * [new tag]               0.9                     -> 0.9
 * [new tag]               0.9.1                   -> 0.9.1
 * [new tag]               0.9.2                   -> 0.9.2
 * [new tag]               0.9.3                   -> 0.9.3
 * [new tag]               0.9.4                   -> 0.9.4
 * [new tag]               0.9.5                   -> 0.9.5
 * [new tag]               0.9.8                   -> 0.9.8
 * [new tag]               0.9.9                   -> 0.9.9
 * [new tag]               1.0.0                   -> 1.0.0
 * [new tag]               1.0.1                   -> 1.0.1
 * [new tag]               1.0.2                   -> 1.0.2
 * [new tag]               1.0.3                   -> 1.0.3
 * [new tag]               1.0.4                   -> 1.0.4
 * [new tag]               1.0.5                   -> 1.0.5
 * [new tag]               1.0.6                   -> 1.0.6
 * [new tag]               1.0.7                   -> 1.0.7
 * [new tag]               1.0.8                   -> 1.0.8
 * [new tag]               1.0.9                   -> 1.0.9
 * [new tag]               1.1.0                   -> 1.1.0
 * [new tag]               1.1.1                   -> 1.1.1
 * [new tag]               1.1.10                  -> 1.1.10
 * [new tag]               1.1.11                  -> 1.1.11
 * [new tag]               1.1.12                  -> 1.1.12
 * [new tag]               1.1.13                  -> 1.1.13
 * [new tag]               1.1.2                   -> 1.1.2
 * [new tag]               1.1.3                   -> 1.1.3
 * [new tag]               1.1.4                   -> 1.1.4
 * [new tag]               1.1.5                   -> 1.1.5
 * [new tag]               1.1.6                   -> 1.1.6
 * [new tag]               1.1.7                   -> 1.1.7
 * [new tag]               1.1.8                   -> 1.1.8
 * [new tag]               1.1.9                   -> 1.1.9
 * [new tag]               1.2.0                   -> 1.2.0
 * [new tag]               1.2.1                   -> 1.2.1
 * [new tag]               1.2.2                   -> 1.2.2
 * [new tag]               1.2.3                   -> 1.2.3
 * [new tag]               1.2.4                   -> 1.2.4
 * [new tag]               1.2.5                   -> 1.2.5
 * [new tag]               1.2.6                   -> 1.2.6
 * [new tag]               1.3.0                   -> 1.3.0
 * [new tag]               1.3.1                   -> 1.3.1
 * [new tag]               1.3.2                   -> 1.3.2
 * [new tag]               1.3.3                   -> 1.3.3
 * [new tag]               1.3.4                   -> 1.3.4
 * [new tag]               1.3.5                   -> 1.3.5
 * [new tag]               1.3.6                   -> 1.3.6
 * [new tag]               1.3.7                   -> 1.3.7
 * [new tag]               1.3.8                   -> 1.3.8
 * [new tag]               1.3.9                   -> 1.3.9
 * [new tag]               1.4.0                   -> 1.4.0
 * [new tag]               1.4.1                   -> 1.4.1
 * [new tag]               1.4.2                   -> 1.4.2
 * [new tag]               1.4.3                   -> 1.4.3
 * [new tag]               1.5.0                   -> 1.5.0
 * [new tag]               1.5.1                   -> 1.5.1
 * [new tag]               1.5.10                  -> 1.5.10
 * [new tag]               1.5.11                  -> 1.5.11
 * [new tag]               1.5.12                  -> 1.5.12
 * [new tag]               1.5.13                  -> 1.5.13
 * [new tag]               1.5.14                  -> 1.5.14
 * [new tag]               1.5.2                   -> 1.5.2
 * [new tag]               1.5.3                   -> 1.5.3
 * [new tag]               1.5.4                   -> 1.5.4
 * [new tag]               1.5.5                   -> 1.5.5
 * [new tag]               1.5.6                   -> 1.5.6
 * [new tag]               1.5.7                   -> 1.5.7
 * [new tag]               1.5.8                   -> 1.5.8
 * [new tag]               1.5.9                   -> 1.5.9
 * [new tag]               1.6.0                   -> 1.6.0
 * [new tag]               1.6.1                   -> 1.6.1
 * [new tag]               1.6.10                  -> 1.6.10
 * [new tag]               1.6.11                  -> 1.6.11
 * [new tag]               1.6.12                  -> 1.6.12
 * [new tag]               1.6.13                  -> 1.6.13
 * [new tag]               1.6.14                  -> 1.6.14
 * [new tag]               1.6.15                  -> 1.6.15
 * [new tag]               1.6.16                  -> 1.6.16
 * [new tag]               1.6.17                  -> 1.6.17
 * [new tag]               1.6.2                   -> 1.6.2
 * [new tag]               1.6.3                   -> 1.6.3
 * [new tag]               1.6.4                   -> 1.6.4
 * [new tag]               1.6.5                   -> 1.6.5
 * [new tag]               1.6.6                   -> 1.6.6
 * [new tag]               1.6.7                   -> 1.6.7
 * [new tag]               1.6.8                   -> 1.6.8
 * [new tag]               1.6.9                   -> 1.6.9
 * [new tag]               1.7.0                   -> 1.7.0
 * [new tag]               1.7.1                   -> 1.7.1
 * [new tag]               1.7.2                   -> 1.7.2
 * [new tag]               1.7.3                   -> 1.7.3
 * [new tag]               1.7.4                   -> 1.7.4
 * [new tag]               1.7.5                   -> 1.7.5
 * [new tag]               1.7.6                   -> 1.7.6
 * [new tag]               1.7.7                   -> 1.7.7
 * [new tag]               1.8.0                   -> 1.8.0
 * [new tag]               1.8.1                   -> 1.8.1
 * [new tag]               1.8.2                   -> 1.8.2
 * [new tag]               1.8.3                   -> 1.8.3
 * [new tag]               1.8.4                   -> 1.8.4
 * [new tag]               1.8.5                   -> 1.8.5
 * [new tag]               1.8.6                   -> 1.8.6
 * [new tag]               1.9.0                   -> 1.9.0
 * [new tag]               1.9.1                   -> 1.9.1
 * [new tag]               1.9.2                   -> 1.9.2
 * [new tag]               1.9.3                   -> 1.9.3
 * [new tag]               2.0.0                   -> 2.0.0
 * [new tag]               2.0.1                   -> 2.0.1
 * [new tag]               2.0.2                   -> 2.0.2
 * [new tag]               2.0.3                   -> 2.0.3
 * [new tag]               2.0.4                   -> 2.0.4
 * [new tag]               2.0.5                   -> 2.0.5
 * [new tag]               2.0.6                   -> 2.0.6
 * [new tag]               2.1.0                   -> 2.1.0
 * [new tag]               2.1.1                   -> 2.1.1
 * [new tag]               2.1.10                  -> 2.1.10
 * [new tag]               2.1.11                  -> 2.1.11
 * [new tag]               2.1.12                  -> 2.1.12
 * [new tag]               2.1.13                  -> 2.1.13
 * [new tag]               2.1.14                  -> 2.1.14
 * [new tag]               2.1.15                  -> 2.1.15
 * [new tag]               2.1.16                  -> 2.1.16
 * [new tag]               2.1.2                   -> 2.1.2
 * [new tag]               2.1.3                   -> 2.1.3
 * [new tag]               2.1.4                   -> 2.1.4
 * [new tag]               2.1.5                   -> 2.1.5
 * [new tag]               2.1.6                   -> 2.1.6
 * [new tag]               2.1.7                   -> 2.1.7
 * [new tag]               2.1.8                   -> 2.1.8
 * [new tag]               2.1.9                   -> 2.1.9
 * [new tag]               2.2.0                   -> 2.2.0
 * [new tag]               2.2.1                   -> 2.2.1
 * [new tag]               2.2.10                  -> 2.2.10
 * [new tag]               2.2.11                  -> 2.2.11
 * [new tag]               2.2.12                  -> 2.2.12
 * [new tag]               2.2.13                  -> 2.2.13
 * [new tag]               2.2.14                  -> 2.2.14
 * [new tag]               2.2.15                  -> 2.2.15
 * [new tag]               2.2.16                  -> 2.2.16
 * [new tag]               2.2.17                  -> 2.2.17
 * [new tag]               2.2.2                   -> 2.2.2
 * [new tag]               2.2.3                   -> 2.2.3
 * [new tag]               2.2.4                   -> 2.2.4
 * [new tag]               2.2.5                   -> 2.2.5
 * [new tag]               2.2.6                   -> 2.2.6
 * [new tag]               2.2.7                   -> 2.2.7
 * [new tag]               2.2.8                   -> 2.2.8
 * [new tag]               2.2.9                   -> 2.2.9
 * [new tag]               2.3.0                   -> 2.3.0
 * [new tag]               2.4.0                   -> 2.4.0
 * [new tag]               2.4.1                   -> 2.4.1
 * [new tag]               2.4.10                  -> 2.4.10
 * [new tag]               2.4.11                  -> 2.4.11
 * [new tag]               2.4.12                  -> 2.4.12
 * [new tag]               2.4.13                  -> 2.4.13
 * [new tag]               2.4.14                  -> 2.4.14
 * [new tag]               2.4.15                  -> 2.4.15
 * [new tag]               2.4.16                  -> 2.4.16
 * [new tag]               2.4.2                   -> 2.4.2
 * [new tag]               2.4.3                   -> 2.4.3
 * [new tag]               2.4.4                   -> 2.4.4
 * [new tag]               2.4.5                   -> 2.4.5
 * [new tag]               2.4.6                   -> 2.4.6
 * [new tag]               2.4.7                   -> 2.4.7
 * [new tag]               2.4.8                   -> 2.4.8
 * [new tag]               2.4.9                   -> 2.4.9
 * [new tag]               2.5.0                   -> 2.5.0
 * [new tag]               2.5.1                   -> 2.5.1
 * [new tag]               2.5.10                  -> 2.5.10
 * [new tag]               2.5.11                  -> 2.5.11
 * [new tag]               2.5.12                  -> 2.5.12
 * [new tag]               2.5.2                   -> 2.5.2
 * [new tag]               2.5.3                   -> 2.5.3
 * [new tag]               2.5.4                   -> 2.5.4
 * [new tag]               2.5.5                   -> 2.5.5
 * [new tag]               2.5.6                   -> 2.5.6
 * [new tag]               2.5.7                   -> 2.5.7
 * [new tag]               2.5.8                   -> 2.5.8
 * [new tag]               2.5.9                   -> 2.5.9
 * [new tag]               2.6.0                   -> 2.6.0
 * [new tag]               2.6.1                   -> 2.6.1
 * [new tag]               2.6.2                   -> 2.6.2
 * [new tag]               2.7.0                   -> 2.7.0
 * [new tag]               2.7.1                   -> 2.7.1
 * [new tag]               2.7.2                   -> 2.7.2
 * [new tag]               2.7.3                   -> 2.7.3
 * [new tag]               2.7.4                   -> 2.7.4
 * [new tag]               2.7.5                   -> 2.7.5
 * [new tag]               2.7.6                   -> 2.7.6
 * [new tag]               2.7.7                   -> 2.7.7
 * [new tag]               3.0.0                   -> 3.0.0
 * [new tag]               3.0.1                   -> 3.0.1
 * [new tag]               3.0.10                  -> 3.0.10
 * [new tag]               3.0.11                  -> 3.0.11
 * [new tag]               3.0.2                   -> 3.0.2
 * [new tag]               3.0.3                   -> 3.0.3
 * [new tag]               3.0.4                   -> 3.0.4
 * [new tag]               3.0.5                   -> 3.0.5
 * [new tag]               3.0.6                   -> 3.0.6
 * [new tag]               3.0.7                   -> 3.0.7
 * [new tag]               3.0.8                   -> 3.0.8
 * [new tag]               3.0.9                   -> 3.0.9
 * [new tag]               3.1.0                   -> 3.1.0
 * [new tag]               3.1.1                   -> 3.1.1
 * [new tag]               3.1.10                  -> 3.1.10
 * [new tag]               3.1.11                  -> 3.1.11
 * [new tag]               3.1.12                  -> 3.1.12
 * [new tag]               3.1.2                   -> 3.1.2
 * [new tag]               3.1.3                   -> 3.1.3
 * [new tag]               3.1.4                   -> 3.1.4
 * [new tag]               3.1.5                   -> 3.1.5
 * [new tag]               3.1.6                   -> 3.1.6
 * [new tag]               3.1.7                   -> 3.1.7
 * [new tag]               3.1.8                   -> 3.1.8
 * [new tag]               3.1.9                   -> 3.1.9
 * [new tag]               3.2.0                   -> 3.2.0
 * [new tag]               3.2.1                   -> 3.2.1
 * [new tag]               3.2.10                  -> 3.2.10
 * [new tag]               3.2.11                  -> 3.2.11
 * [new tag]               3.2.12                  -> 3.2.12
 * [new tag]               3.2.13                  -> 3.2.13
 * [new tag]               3.2.14                  -> 3.2.14
 * [new tag]               3.2.15                  -> 3.2.15
 * [new tag]               3.2.16                  -> 3.2.16
 * [new tag]               3.2.17                  -> 3.2.17
 * [new tag]               3.2.2                   -> 3.2.2
 * [new tag]               3.2.3                   -> 3.2.3
 * [new tag]               3.2.4                   -> 3.2.4
 * [new tag]               3.2.5                   -> 3.2.5
 * [new tag]               3.2.6                   -> 3.2.6
 * [new tag]               3.2.7                   -> 3.2.7
 * [new tag]               3.2.8                   -> 3.2.8
 * [new tag]               3.2.9                   -> 3.2.9
 * [new tag]               3.3.0                   -> 3.3.0
 * [new tag]               3.3.1                   -> 3.3.1
 * [new tag]               3.3.10                  -> 3.3.10
 * [new tag]               3.3.11                  -> 3.3.11
 * [new tag]               3.3.12                  -> 3.3.12
 * [new tag]               3.3.13                  -> 3.3.13
 * [new tag]               3.3.14                  -> 3.3.14
 * [new tag]               3.3.15                  -> 3.3.15
 * [new tag]               3.3.16                  -> 3.3.16
 * [new tag]               3.3.2                   -> 3.3.2
 * [new tag]               3.3.3                   -> 3.3.3
 * [new tag]               3.3.4                   -> 3.3.4
 * [new tag]               3.3.5                   -> 3.3.5
 * [new tag]               3.3.6                   -> 3.3.6
 * [new tag]               3.3.7                   -> 3.3.7
 * [new tag]               3.3.8                   -> 3.3.8
 * [new tag]               3.3.9                   -> 3.3.9
 * [new tag]               3.4.0                   -> 3.4.0
 * [new tag]               3.4.1                   -> 3.4.1
 * [new tag]               3.4.10                  -> 3.4.10
 * [new tag]               3.4.11                  -> 3.4.11
 * [new tag]               3.4.2                   -> 3.4.2
 * [new tag]               3.4.3                   -> 3.4.3
 * [new tag]               3.4.4                   -> 3.4.4
 * [new tag]               3.4.5                   -> 3.4.5
 * [new tag]               3.4.6                   -> 3.4.6
 * [new tag]               3.4.7                   -> 3.4.7
 * [new tag]               3.4.8                   -> 3.4.8
 * [new tag]               3.4.9                   -> 3.4.9
 * [new tag]               3.5.0                   -> 3.5.0
 * [new tag]               3.5.1                   -> 3.5.1
 * [new tag]               3.5.10                  -> 3.5.10
 * [new tag]               3.5.2                   -> 3.5.2
 * [new tag]               3.5.3                   -> 3.5.3
 * [new tag]               3.5.4                   -> 3.5.4
 * [new tag]               3.5.5                   -> 3.5.5
 * [new tag]               3.5.6                   -> 3.5.6
 * [new tag]               3.5.7                   -> 3.5.7
 * [new tag]               3.5.8                   -> 3.5.8
 * [new tag]               3.5.9                   -> 3.5.9
 * [new tag]               3.6.0                   -> 3.6.0
 * [new tag]               3.6.1                   -> 3.6.1
 * [new tag]               3.6.10                  -> 3.6.10
 * [new tag]               3.6.11                  -> 3.6.11
 * [new tag]               3.6.12                  -> 3.6.12
 * [new tag]               3.6.13                  -> 3.6.13
 * [new tag]               3.6.14                  -> 3.6.14
 * [new tag]               3.6.15                  -> 3.6.15
 * [new tag]               3.6.16                  -> 3.6.16
 * [new tag]               3.6.17                  -> 3.6.17
 * [new tag]               3.6.18                  -> 3.6.18
 * [new tag]               3.6.19                  -> 3.6.19
 * [new tag]               3.6.2                   -> 3.6.2
 * [new tag]               3.6.20                  -> 3.6.20
 * [new tag]               3.6.21                  -> 3.6.21
 * [new tag]               3.6.3                   -> 3.6.3
 * [new tag]               3.6.4                   -> 3.6.4
 * [new tag]               3.6.5                   -> 3.6.5
 * [new tag]               3.6.6                   -> 3.6.6
 * [new tag]               3.6.7                   -> 3.6.7
 * [new tag]               3.6.8                   -> 3.6.8
 * [new tag]               3.6.9                   -> 3.6.9
 * [new tag]               4.0.0                   -> 4.0.0
 * [new tag]               4.0.1                   -> 4.0.1
 * [new tag]               4.0.10                  -> 4.0.10
 * [new tag]               4.0.11                  -> 4.0.11
 * [new tag]               4.0.12                  -> 4.0.12
 * [new tag]               4.0.13                  -> 4.0.13
 * [new tag]               4.0.14                  -> 4.0.14
 * [new tag]               4.0.15                  -> 4.0.15
 * [new tag]               4.0.16                  -> 4.0.16
 * [new tag]               4.0.17                  -> 4.0.17
 * [new tag]               4.0.18                  -> 4.0.18
 * [new tag]               4.0.19                  -> 4.0.19
 * [new tag]               4.0.2                   -> 4.0.2
 * [new tag]               4.0.20                  -> 4.0.20
 * [new tag]               4.0.21                  -> 4.0.21
 * [new tag]               4.0.22                  -> 4.0.22
 * [new tag]               4.0.23                  -> 4.0.23
 * [new tag]               4.0.24                  -> 4.0.24
 * [new tag]               4.0.25                  -> 4.0.25
 * [new tag]               4.0.26                  -> 4.0.26
 * [new tag]               4.0.27                  -> 4.0.27
 * [new tag]               4.0.28                  -> 4.0.28
 * [new tag]               4.0.3                   -> 4.0.3
 * [new tag]               4.0.4                   -> 4.0.4
 * [new tag]               4.0.5                   -> 4.0.5
 * [new tag]               4.0.6                   -> 4.0.6
 * [new tag]               4.0.7                   -> 4.0.7
 * [new tag]               4.0.8                   -> 4.0.8
 * [new tag]               4.0.9                   -> 4.0.9
 * [new tag]               4.1.0                   -> 4.1.0
 * [new tag]               4.1.1                   -> 4.1.1
 * [new tag]               4.1.10                  -> 4.1.10
 * [new tag]               4.1.11                  -> 4.1.11
 * [new tag]               4.1.12                  -> 4.1.12
 * [new tag]               4.1.13                  -> 4.1.13
 * [new tag]               4.1.14                  -> 4.1.14
 * [new tag]               4.1.15                  -> 4.1.15
 * [new tag]               4.1.16                  -> 4.1.16
 * [new tag]               4.1.17                  -> 4.1.17
 * [new tag]               4.1.18                  -> 4.1.18
 * [new tag]               4.1.19                  -> 4.1.19
 * [new tag]               4.1.2                   -> 4.1.2
 * [new tag]               4.1.20                  -> 4.1.20
 * [new tag]               4.1.21                  -> 4.1.21
 * [new tag]               4.1.22                  -> 4.1.22
 * [new tag]               4.1.23                  -> 4.1.23
 * [new tag]               4.1.24                  -> 4.1.24
 * [new tag]               4.1.25                  -> 4.1.25
 * [new tag]               4.1.3                   -> 4.1.3
 * [new tag]               4.1.4                   -> 4.1.4
 * [new tag]               4.1.5                   -> 4.1.5
 * [new tag]               4.1.6                   -> 4.1.6
 * [new tag]               4.1.7                   -> 4.1.7
 * [new tag]               4.1.8                   -> 4.1.8
 * [new tag]               4.2.0                   -> 4.2.0
 * [new tag]               4.2.1                   -> 4.2.1
 * [new tag]               4.2.10                  -> 4.2.10
 * [new tag]               4.2.11                  -> 4.2.11
 * [new tag]               4.2.12                  -> 4.2.12
 * [new tag]               4.2.13                  -> 4.2.13
 * [new tag]               4.2.15                  -> 4.2.15
 * [new tag]               4.2.16                  -> 4.2.16
 * [new tag]               4.2.17                  -> 4.2.17
 * [new tag]               4.2.18                  -> 4.2.18
 * [new tag]               4.2.19                  -> 4.2.19
 * [new tag]               4.2.2                   -> 4.2.2
 * [new tag]               4.2.20                  -> 4.2.20
 * [new tag]               4.2.21                  -> 4.2.21
 * [new tag]               4.2.3                   -> 4.2.3
 * [new tag]               4.2.4                   -> 4.2.4
 * [new tag]               4.2.5                   -> 4.2.5
 * [new tag]               4.2.6                   -> 4.2.6
 * [new tag]               4.2.7                   -> 4.2.7
 * [new tag]               4.2.8                   -> 4.2.8
 * [new tag]               4.2.9                   -> 4.2.9
 * [new tag]               4.3.0                   -> 4.3.0
 * [new tag]               4.3.1                   -> 4.3.1
 * [new tag]               4.3.2                   -> 4.3.2
 * [new tag]               4.3.3                   -> 4.3.3
remote: Enumerating objects: 33, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 33 (delta 20), reused 20 (delta 20), pack-reused 13
Unpacking objects: 100% (33/33), 5.60 KiB | 69.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
 * [new tag]               4.0.29     -> 4.0.29
 * [new tag]               4.1.9      -> 4.1.9
 * [new tag]               4.2.14     -> 4.2.14
Updating files: 100% (2315/2315), done.
Switched to a new branch 'stable'
==> Updating Homebrew...
Error: Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json!
Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json!
Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula_tap_migrations.jws.json!
Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask_tap_migrations.jws.json!
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-ruby/blobs/sha256:5c86a23e0e3caee1a4cfd958ed7d50a38e752ebaf2e7c5717e5c8eabaa6e9f12
Already downloaded: /Users/fenris-esxi/Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-3.3.2.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring portable-ruby-3.3.2.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --user-agent Homebrew/4.3.3\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 14.5\)\ curl/8.6.0 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --progress-bar --silent --remote-time --output /Users/fenris-esxi/Library/Caches/Homebrew/api/formula.jws.json --location --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.3.3\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 14.5\)\ curl/8.6.0 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --progress-bar --silent --compressed --speed-limit 100 --speed-time 5 https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json` exited with 23. Here's the output:
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force --quiet

This is what I'm faced with, so I gave up went to the Homebrew site, downloaded the pkg file, installed it. No problems with the install using that method, but then when I go back to the terminal, it wouldn't recognize the brew command

Are you virtualizing macOS somehow or is that user name just a coincidence?

Yes, MacOS 14.5 Soloma is running on VMware ESXi 6.7, and it works so nice and its flawless

I think I may have fixed this problem...
first: sudo rm -fr $(brew --cache)
second:curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh | sed 's/"update" "--force" "--quiet"/"update" "--force" "--verbose" "--debug"/' > /tmp/install.sh
bash /tmp/install.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/install.log
